# ERROR in multi ../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/index.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, polaris

Im trying to run webpack-dev-server but getting the below error:

ERROR in multi ../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/index.js' in '/home/dinesh/Shopify_Test_New/shopify_app/bin'
@ multi ../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/index.js

- Node Version: 10.6.0
- NPM Version: 1.7.0
- webpack Version: 4.16.5
- webpack-dev-server Version: 2.11.1

  webpack.config.js

  ```
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  var config = {

     entry: "./app/index.js",

    resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist', // `dist` is the destination
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
  };

  module.exports = config;
  ```